# Is there a faster way to select objects?

Tags: mesh

I'm on Part II: Step 4 of Sims4Studio.com/thread/164/start-finish-access

Every time, I right click each line, I will miss a click, all my previous selections disappear.

I have been using blender for two years off and on. I still don't get it.  I wish the devs knew the level of difficulty they have added to the GUI. Forget tutorials. Every person is hitting their keyboards without explaining which keys or functions complete each action.

This is just one of my 99 problems.

Answer (score 2):

In Blender, selection and deselection operations are included in the undo stack. This means you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to undo any time you incorrectly select or deselect something.

The developers tie so many operations to keyboard shortcuts because it's a lot more time efficient for users that are familiar with them. Most operations can still be accessed through menus, and nearly all of them can be accessed by searching with <kbd>F3</kbd> (or the spacebar in older versions.) You can see (and change) all keyboard shortcuts by going to 'Edit > Preferences' and clicking 'Keymap' on the left side.

Comment: Shift + Alt seems to pick groups of objects I want to delete.  B (box tool) does doesn't work in edit mode. Options = Solid Shading + Off Limit Selection to Visible . I can b + cursor over  the item all day, press x, tick delete vertices, item remains. What are the proper options to get Blender 2.70 to remove vertices?

Comment: I've never used Blender 2.70 so I'm afraid I won't be able to help with its shortcuts. Seeing as that version was released 6 years ago (March 2014), I'd highly recommend updating to Blender 2.8.x. Not only have there been major improvements to the user interface and technology in general, there's also a far more active community, so you're more likely to be able to get help. The only case in which you shouldn't update is if the scene you're working on has technical limitations that require the old version.